# How to get default product attribute set id?

Tags: magento

I need to get default product attribute set id in helper. I can get it using

```
$catalogProductEntityTypeId = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getResource()->getTypeId();
$defaultAttributeSetId = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_set')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_set_name', 'Default')
            ->addFieldToFilter('entity_type_id', $catalogProductEntityTypeId)
            ->getFirstItem()
            ->getId();
```

But may be somebody know easier way with less code amount?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A shorter version would be this:

```
$sDefaultAttributeSetId = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
    ->getEntityType(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY)
    ->getDefaultAttributeSetId();
```